# Cloning,Copying prolog list

Tags: prolog, copy, clone

I found this piece of code everywhere for **copying a list or cloning** a list.

***Code found everywhere:***

```
clone([],[]).
clone([H|T],[H|Z]):- clone(T,Z).

?-clone([1,2,3],Z).
  Z=[1,2,3]

?-clone(2,Z).
  false
```

This doesn't copy anything other than `lists`.The time complexity of the above code is `O(n)`.

But Prolog tries to unify right and lift side, right? This can be written in a much simpler way, right?

Like `clone1(Z,Z).`:

```
clone1(Z,Z).

?-clone1([1,2,3],Z).
  Z=[1,2,3]
?-clone1(1,Z).
  Z=1
?-clone1(!,Z).
  Z =!
?-clone1(@,Z).
  Z=(@)
```

I feel `clone1(X, X).` is much more generic and cloned almost everything passed to it. It did not  clone `%` ,`(` , `)` , `()`. `clone1(%,Z)` failed with the message `% - used for commenting`.The time complexity of `clone1` is `O(1)` I may be wrong. In every aspect, `clone1` is much better than `clone`.

Why is this clone/copy written not like this, i.e. `clone(X, X).` What am I missing? Please explain to me the difference between both codes I provided above. If both do the same why is `clone1(X, X).` not used and no one had posted about it.

Comment: You're right second definition of copy is much more expressive. Though you want to use the first definition if you want to force your predicate succeed only for lists. Something similar to first definition would be `clone2(Z,Z):- islist(Z)` but first definition is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `clone1(Z,Z2)` is the same as calling `Z = Z2`. Which is even more basic.

The difference is, as you've pointed out yourself, that `clone/2` works only for lists, while `=/2` works for all valid Prolog terms.

Another point to the code is to learn about list handling in Prolog; for it to serve as the basis for other recursive list-handling tasks you might want to write. Like mapping, filtering, counting, etc.

Sterling and Shapiro book calls such code a *skeleton code* for a certain data type.

Comment: No one ever mentioned `clone1(X,X).` I think it's worth mentioning `clone1(X,X).` When your task can be completed with basic prolog unification. But I got your point @Will Ness Everyone posted to make others understand list handling. But they should have mentioned this also.

Comment: I think I did see it when I learned Prolog, in some books/tutorials, under "you could implement your own `=`". Like, `my_same(A,A)`.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you suggest some good material on prolog. I want increase knowledge in prolog. Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info. :) there's also the book by  [Bratko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Bratko_(computer_scientist)), Sterling and Shapiro's "The Art of Prolog", [Richard O'Keefe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_O%27Keefe)'s "The Craft of Prolog", "Clause and Effect" by W. Clocksin ...

Comment: and, "Forbus,K.,de Kleer,J.: Building Problem Solvers".

Comment: I'll make to look into the material you provided. Thanks for taking out your time to help me. Really means a lot.

Comment: [BPS: the link](http://www.qrg.northwestern.edu/BPS/readme.html). this is all really very old stuff, from the 80s and the 90s. :) (and [another one](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691637709/the-implementation-of-prolog))

Comment: Now I have a lot of resources to cover. XD I'll start with sterling and Shapiro's The art of prolog. Really means a lot coming from an OG like you.

Answer (score 7):

One thing to keep in mind is what you exactly mean by "clone" or "copy". What happens to variables?

For example, if you use unification for cloning, then:

```
| ?- L1 = [1,2,X], L2 = L1.

L1 = [1,2,X]
L2 = [1,2,X]

yes
| ?- L1 = [1,2,X], L2 = L1, X = a.

L1 = [1,2,a]
L2 = [1,2,a]
X = a

yes
| ?-
```

In other words, with unification, any corresponding variables that are "copied" or "cloned" in this way remain unified (since the terms are unified).

If you want new variables when you "clone" or "copy", you would want to use Prolog's `copy_term/2`:

```
| ?-  L1 = [1,2,X], copy_term(L1, L2), X = a.

L1 = [1,2,a]
L2 = [1,2,_]
X = a

yes
| ?-
```

So now `L2` is a copy of `L1` with it's own variable in the 3rd position in the list.

Comment: Learnt something new `copy_term/2`. This answer was informative. Thanks for taking out your time.